# axis doesn't appear on barchart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am just starting D3 and JS and I am trying to add an X axis to the barchart. It doesn't appear. I think this is because `svg.append("g")` at the bottom of my code is incorrect (there is no variable g). What varaible should be there instead?

barchart.js

```
// Create data array of values to visualize
var dataArray = [23, 13, 21, 14, 37, 15, 18, 34, 30];

// Create variable for the SVG
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
          .attr("height","100%")
          .attr("width","100%");

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
          .attr("class", "bar")
          .attr("height", function(d, i) {return (d * 10)})
          .attr("width","40")
          .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 25})
          .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 400 - (d * 10)});

// Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {return d})
           .attr("class", "text")
           .attr("x", function(d, i) {return (i * 60) + 36})
           .attr("y", function(d, i) {return 415 - (d * 10)});

//add axis
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);
```

Comment: What is x in   .scale(x) ?

Comment: Are you using d3.v3? If so why not use v4? Also I don't see any domain or range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The xAxis is translated in the y to height so it can't be seen as it is outside the svg.

I fixed the height and width. Gave the text a colour of white.

What did you want on the x-axis?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title></title>
</head>
<script src="//d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>

<body>

</body>
<script>
  var width = 600;
  var height = 600;
  // Create data array of values to visualize
  var dataArray = [23, 13, 21, 14, 37, 15, 18, 34, 30];

  var xScale = d3.scale.linear().range([0, width]);
  // var yScale = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  // Create variable for the SVG
  var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("height", 600)
    .attr("width", 600);

  // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to rectangles for bar chart
  svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("height", function(d, i) {
      return (d * 10)
    })
    .attr("width", "40")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 60) + 25
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return 400 - (d * 10)
    });

  // Select, append to SVG, and add attributes to text
  svg.selectAll("text")
    .data(dataArray)
    .enter().append("text")
    .text(function(d) {
      return d
    })
    .attr("class", "text")
    .attr("x", function(d, i) {
      return (i * 60) + 36
    })
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
      return 415 - (d * 10)
    })
    .style("fill", "white");

  //add axis
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xScale)
    .orient("bottom");

  // var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
  //     .orient("left").ticks(5);

  svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0, 420)")
    .call(xAxis);
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: In fairness I think Gerardo's answer is better. He doesn't even get an acknowledgement. He is the goto person for any d3 problems. If you get off on the wrong foot with him, things will be much more difficult for you.

Answer (score 1):

"g" is not a variable, it's the group (`<g>`) element in the SVG.

The problem here seems to be this line:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
```

If `height` is the height of the SVG, nothing will show up because you are translating the axis to the end of the SVG.

The solution, therefore, is translating it to a value less than that:

```
.attr("transform", "translate(0," + (height - padding) + ")")
```